# invoke existing war file in tomcat from batch script

Tags: java

I need to invoke a existing war file in tomcat by giving input arguments from a batch script. My folder structure in tomcat/webapps is:
-bin
com
metir
explorer
HtmlDumper.class
-WebContent
META-INF
MANIFEST.MF
-WEB-INF

The main calss is `HtmlDumper.class`

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: What a batch script you are talking about?

Comment: It is a windows batch script.

Answer (score 2):

WAR files aren't intended to be executed outside of a container. Given that Tomcat will expand your WAR file into `webapps`, you have access to the class files that were bundled into the WAR and can [run them with `java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) like any other class. If you're in a position where you need to do this, though, you've probably done something very wrong.

Comment: how to invoke my war file in tomcat from a batch script by giving input variables?

Comment: You don't "invoke" a war file. You [deploy it in a container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html), like Tomcat, after which it may be used by the container to [service HTTP requests](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/geysj.html).